# Hide grand-parent class when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, css, class, checkbox, parent

I need to hide the first class below (wfob_wrap) when checkbox (wfob_checkbox) is checked.
I tried many ways with no success.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

```
<div id="wfob_wrap" class="wfob_wrap_start">
  <div class="wfob_wrapper" data-wfob-id="72396">
    <div class="wfob_bump wfob_clear" data-product-key="wfob_5fb3c4fc409e4" data-wfob-id="72396">
      <div class="wfob_outer">
        <div class="wfob_Box">
          <div class="wfob_bgBox_table no_table">
            <div class="wfob_bgBox_tablecell no_table_cell wfob_check_container">
              <div class="wfob_order_wrap wfob_content_bottom_wrap">
                <div class="wfob_bgBox_table_box">
                  <div class="wfob_bgBox_cell wfob_img_box">
                    <div class="wfob_checkbox_input_wrap">
                      <span class="wfob_bump_checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="wfob_checkbox wfob_bump_product" checked="">
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this should work: `document.querySelector(".wfob_checkbox").addEventListener("change", () => document.querySelector("#wfob_wrap > div").style.display = document.querySelector(".wfob_checkbox").checked ? "none" : "");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('[type=checkbox]').addEventListener('change', e => {
  e.target.closest('#wfob_wrap').firstElementChild.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div id="wfob_wrap" class="wfob_wrap_start">
  <div class="wfob_wrapper" data-wfob-id="72396">
    <div class="wfob_bump wfob_clear" data-product-key="wfob_5fb3c4fc409e4" data-wfob-id="72396">
      <div class="wfob_outer">
        <div class="wfob_Box">
          <div class="wfob_bgBox_table no_table">
            <div class="wfob_bgBox_tablecell no_table_cell wfob_check_container">
              <div class="wfob_order_wrap wfob_content_bottom_wrap">
                <div class="wfob_bgBox_table_box">
                  <div class="wfob_bgBox_cell wfob_img_box">
                    <div class="wfob_checkbox_input_wrap">
                      <span class="wfob_bump_checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="wfob_checkbox wfob_bump_product" checked="">
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used [.closest(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the `#wfob_wrap` element and [.firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) to get this element's first child.

In this specific case, since the element you're looking for has an id, you don't need `.closest(..)`, you can get that element directly using `document.getElementById('wfob_wrap')`.

Comment: This will not work if the checkbox is already checked

Comment: No need to use closest when you have ID

Answer (score 0):

I gave two solutions for javascript and jquery. Was it necessary?

jquery version:

```js
$('.wfob_checkbox.wfob_bump_product').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).closest('#wfob_wrap .wfob_wrapper').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wfob_wrap" class="wfob_wrap_start">
  <div class="wfob_wrapper" data-wfob-id="72396">
    <div class="wfob_bump wfob_clear" data-product-key="wfob_5fb3c4fc409e4" data-wfob-id="72396">
      <div class="wfob_outer">
        <div class="wfob_Box">
          <div class="wfob_bgBox_table no_table">
            <div class="wfob_bgBox_tablecell no_table_cell wfob_check_container">
              <div class="wfob_order_wrap wfob_content_bottom_wrap">
                <div class="wfob_bgBox_table_box">
                  <div class="wfob_bgBox_cell wfob_img_box">
                    <div class="wfob_checkbox_input_wrap">
                      <span class="wfob_bump_checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="wfob_checkbox wfob_bump_product">
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript version:

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector('.wfob_checkbox.wfob_bump_product');

checkbox.onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    this.closest('.wfob_wrapper').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wfob_wrap" class="wfob_wrap_start">
  <div class="wfob_wrapper" data-wfob-id="72396">
    <div class="wfob_bump wfob_clear" data-product-key="wfob_5fb3c4fc409e4" data-wfob-id="72396">
      <div class="wfob_outer">
        <div class="wfob_Box">
          <div class="wfob_bgBox_table no_table">
            <div class="wfob_bgBox_tablecell no_table_cell wfob_check_container">
              <div class="wfob_order_wrap wfob_content_bottom_wrap">
                <div class="wfob_bgBox_table_box">
                  <div class="wfob_bgBox_cell wfob_img_box">
                    <div class="wfob_checkbox_input_wrap">
                      <span class="wfob_bump_checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="wfob_checkbox wfob_bump_product">
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work if the checkbox is already checked. Also no need for closest when you have an ID

Comment: This is a jQuery answer, the question is not tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @caramba, the author of the question did not say what he strictly needs for Javascript, and even more so, I gave a second version for Javascript.

Comment: @mplungjan, the author of the question did not ask for this in his problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It can handle that the checkbox is checked on load

The first is for one checkbox, then second for many.

```js
const toggle = function() {
  const chk = document.querySelector(".wfob_checkbox");
  chk.closest(".wfob_wrapper").classList.toggle("hide", chk.checked)
};  
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.querySelector(".wfob_checkbox").addEventListener("click",toggle)
  toggle()
});
```

```css
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="wfob_wrap" class="wfob_wrap_start">
  <div class="wfob_wrapper" data-wfob-id="72396">
    <div class="wfob_bump wfob_clear" data-product-key="wfob_5fb3c4fc409e4" data-wfob-id="72396">
      <div class="wfob_outer">
        <div class="wfob_Box">
          <div class="wfob_bgBox_table no_table">
            <div class="wfob_bgBox_tablecell no_table_cell wfob_check_container">
              <div class="wfob_order_wrap wfob_content_bottom_wrap">
                <div class="wfob_bgBox_table_box">
                  <div class="wfob_bgBox_cell wfob_img_box">
                    <div class="wfob_checkbox_input_wrap">
                      <span class="wfob_bump_checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="wfob_checkbox wfob_bump_product">
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have more sets, you cannot use IDs

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("wfob_checkbox")) {
      tgt.closest(".wfob_wrap_start").querySelector(".wfob_wrapper").classList.toggle("hide", tgt.checked)
    }
  });
  
  // loading
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".wfob_checkbox:checked")].forEach(tgt => 
      tgt.closest(".wfob_wrap_start").querySelector(".wfob_wrapper").classList.toggle("hide", tgt.checked)
  )    
  
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="wfob_wrap_start">
    <div class="wfob_wrapper" data-wfob-id="72396">
      <div class="wfob_bump wfob_clear" data-product-key="wfob_5fb3c4fc409e4" data-wfob-id="72396">
        <div class="wfob_outer">
          <div class="wfob_Box">
            <div class="wfob_bgBox_table no_table">
              <div class="wfob_bgBox_tablecell no_table_cell wfob_check_container">
                <div class="wfob_order_wrap wfob_content_bottom_wrap">
                  <div class="wfob_bgBox_table_box">
                    <div class="wfob_bgBox_cell wfob_img_box">
                      <div class="wfob_checkbox_input_wrap">
                        <span class="wfob_bump_checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="wfob_checkbox wfob_bump_product">
                      </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wfob_wrap_start">
    <div class="wfob_wrapper" data-wfob-id="72396">
      <div class="wfob_bump wfob_clear" data-product-key="wfob_5fb3c4fc409e4" data-wfob-id="72396">
        <div class="wfob_outer">
          <div class="wfob_Box">
            <div class="wfob_bgBox_table no_table">
              <div class="wfob_bgBox_tablecell no_table_cell wfob_check_container">
                <div class="wfob_order_wrap wfob_content_bottom_wrap">
                  <div class="wfob_bgBox_table_box">
                    <div class="wfob_bgBox_cell wfob_img_box">
                      <div class="wfob_checkbox_input_wrap">
                        <span class="wfob_bump_checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="wfob_checkbox wfob_bump_product" checked>
                      </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```